Saving classification in graduated symbology in QGIS
I have defined my classes (12) in QGIS myself. It has to be always the same, even though some values might not be present. This took a while.
How can I save this as a template for later?


https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#symbology-properties - this is directly mentioned in the first tip of that section.

Look at styles files (qml).
